# Как поместить иконку на кнопку?

Tags: java, изображения, swing, иконки

Как правильно добавить иконку на кнопку? Пробовал так:

```
JButton print_button = new JButton();
ImageIcon print_icon = new ImageIcon("images/print.png");
print_button.setIcon(print_icon);
print_button.setText("Печать");
print_button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
```

и так:

```
JButton delete_button = new JButton("Удалить");
ImageIcon delete_icon = new ImageIcon("..//images/delete.png");
delete_button.setIcon(delete_icon);
```

В обоих случаях иконки не отображаются. Папку `images` поместил и в папку `src`с файлом `.java` и в папку с файлом `.class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Папку с картинками нужно было помещать не в папку src, а рядом с ней...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```java
ButtonName.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/путь/icon.png")));
```

Comment: Так ругается на getClass()

Comment: в таком случае вместо getClass нужно написать Main.class(где Main название класса)